How to select all DOM elements that have a certain class but also have certain CSS attribute value using JavaScript?
How to select all DOM elements that have a certain class but also have certain CSS attribute value using JavaScript?
For example, I want to select all the elements that have class "date" but have a display: none CSS attribute.
I know it has something to do with querySelector / querySelectorAll but I am unable to find such example (all the examples I stumbled upon either select by class or by CSS attribute but not by both).

I'd be surprised if there's a way to do this.  Elements could inherit styles from any number of places.  It might be set directly on the element, might be from CSS which targets a class or ID or anything else, might inherit from a parent element, might have multiple values from multiple sources, etc.  What's the underlying need here?  I suspect this is a bit of an XY Problem.

"all the examples I stumbled upon either select by class or by CSS attribute but not by both" Could you clarify what you mean by "by CSS attribute" here? You can't select by computed value, which is what display: none actually is.

@David i know there is a way since few days ago i used a certain famous AI generative tool to tell me the answer to this question but now that tool now isn't loading so i decided to try my luck here. The need here is i have predefined elements that are display: none at the beginning, and then when a button is clicked 1 elements gets revealed at a time (i know i can do this with adding children elements but i have bad experience with it and i know the total number of elements possible)

you can do this by combining the class selector with the attribute selector in the querySelector(All) method. Here is how you can select all elements with the class date and a CSS attribute display: none for example.
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.date[style*="display: none"]');


It's probably worth noting that this is extremely limited.  If the spacing in the style attribute doesn't match perfectly, it won't find it.  If the CSS rule is applied in any way other than the style attribute, it won't find it.  Basically this doesn't select by CSS style, it's just doing a text match in a standard attribute selector like any other attribute, no different from the now deleted answer just with a different attribute.

@David i didn't know this is a text match search and not a CSS style search... Thanks for the clarification!

I don't know if you can do this with querySelector/querySelectorAll, but you can use this method:


function select(classname, property, value) {
  var elements = [];
  var classes = document.getElementsByClassName(classname);
  for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    if (classes[i].style[property] == value) {
      elements.push(classes[i])
    }
  }
  return elements;
}

console.log(select("date", "display", "none"));
<html>
<body>
  <div style="display:none" class="date">Date1</div>
  <div class="date">Date2</div>
  <div style="display:none" class="date">Date3</div>
  <div class="date">Date4</div>
</body>
</html>



